# groovy script regular expression to get digit

Tags: groovy

I have the following string "INCIDENT: (5 active alarms): abc_log_001:" (no double quotes)

I want to write a regular expression in java groovy to get the digit '5' I tried the below but

```
    def m = parent =~ /(INCIDENT: \\d+))/;
if(!m)
{
        throw new Exception("Could not parse alarm count from parent : ${parent}");
    }

    def alarmCount = m[0][1];
```

It throws an error that

unexpected token: if @ line 13, column 2.
    if (!m)

How to fix this and get the value?

Thanks,

Comment: write your regexp correctly: https://regexr.com/ and fix your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because your regex is malformed and therefore your whole code won't compile

def m = parent =~ /(INCIDENT: \d+)**)**/

Remove the surplus closing parentheses first.

Secondly, your regex won't match anyways. You need to include all characters in your string and group only the number part.

Fix:

```
def parent = "INCIDENT: (5 active alarms): abc_log_001:"
def m = parent =~ /^INCIDENT: \((\d+).*\).*$/
if (!m) {
    throw new Exception("Could not parse alarm count from parent : ${parent}")
}

println m.group(1)
```